# Can't run Google Earth with Ironhide - libGL.so.1 wrong elf class

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, nvidia-optimus, google-earth

I've got a working ironhide setup (ubuntu 11.10). Most applications works fine with the nvidia-drivers (nvidia-current), but I can't get Google Earth (64bit .deb installed) working with or without optirun. Anyone know how to fix this?

ERROR: ld.so: object 'librrfaker.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
./googleearth-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command in a terminal:

```
optirun32 /opt/google/earth/free/google-earth
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Google Earth is 32-bit.

On Ubuntu Oneiric and later, there is a different method to install 32-bit libraries. For libGL.so:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

I recommend Bumblebee over Ironhide, see [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)

Comment: Thanks, is Ironhide not being maintained any longer? I have really no issues with Ironhide except I can't get Google Earth running.

Comment: Martin is very busy with other stuff, http://www.martin-juhl.dk/2012/01/ironhide-is-sleeping-but-not-forever/. Currently, Bumblebee provides more stable features than Ironhide and the only missing thing is a UI, but that will be fixed in a later version.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure [`ia32-libs`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/oneiric/ia32-libs) is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

What's sure is that you need the 32 bit version of libGL because Google still don't provide a 64 bit version of google-earth.

Comment: It says 64bit on the Google Earth download page, but I can try this. I'm just wondering if installing this package may cause havoc on my system since I've already got the 64bit version installed?

Comment: The "64bit " version you're referring to is a 32bit one linked to 32bit libraries, there's no real 64bit executable, that's why it's complaining about "wrong ELF class", therefore, you need ia32-libs.

Comment: You shouldn't get any issue doing this not to mention it may already be installed.

Comment: Seems ia32-libs is already installed on my system...

Comment: What gives you `ldd /opt/google/earth/free/googleearth-bin |grep libGL.so` ?

Comment: Output: libGL.so.1 => not found
 libGL.so.1 => not found

Comment: Well, that's weird because it should be installed by ia32-libs. `ll /usr/lib32/libGL.so` ? Then maybe try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib32 google-earth`. You can use `apt-file search libGL.so` to locate the library and point to the folder using LD_LIBRARY_PATH (though it's a controversial workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/q/882110/343834)

Comment: ll /usr/lib32/libGL.so gives: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 2011-10-07 22:30 /usr/lib32/libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so.1  Does this mean it points to the wrong path?

Comment: No, it means that libGL.so is a link to /usr/lib32/mesa/libGL.so.1 which should also be correctly installed.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, the words "wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64" seem to suggest that Google-earth is trying to load a 64-bit library whereas the Google-earth executable is actually 32-bit (or vice-versa).

What version of Ubuntu are you using (x86 or x86-64) and are you sure you're using the corresponding version of Google earth? The download page for Google earth offers both 32 and 64-bit versions.
[Download Google earth](http://earth.google.com/download-earth.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm running x86-64 ubuntu and I've also installed 64bit version of Google Earth.