# Steam, launching Team Fortress 2: libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, steam

After I got Steam running with the workaround mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216367/steam-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgl-so-1-wrong-elf-class-elfcla), I've got nearly the same problem when launching Team Fortress 2.

After starting it from Steam the "Launcher" pops up and after a few seconds it disappears with the following error in the terminal:

```
/home/user/Steam/SteamApps/steamuser/Team Fortress 2/hl2_linux: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Game removed: AppID 440 "Team Fortress 2", ProcID 5299 
saving roaming config store to 'sharedconfig.vdf'
roaming config store 2 saved successfully
```

Because of the similarity with the workaround I used before, I tried to execute:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib32:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

directly before launching the game, but there is no difference.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081405&page=2):

> Or, instead of editing the file ld.so.conf directly, create a file
>   called local.conf in the subdirectory /etc/ld.so.conf.d containing
>   just the line /usr/local/lib. That is,
>
> Contents of /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf:
>
> /usr/lib32
>
> Then run the sudo ldconfig command.