# no GUI after installing amd catalyst driver

Tags: unity, drivers, ati, lightdm

I'm running a DELL inspiron 3537 with 64 Ubuntu 14.04.

After [asking around](https://github.com/KillaW0lf04/The-Witcher-2-Issues/issues/63) I've decided to install the drivers for the computer. Here's what I did:

- install the intel driver [from here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/)
- reboot (everything was fine)
- install the amd driver [from here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64#amd-catalyst-packages)
- reboot

Now, greeter was working just fine, but when logging in, there's just blank. No unity, no desktop, no nothing. No reaction either. The mouse works, its not freezing and I can go to the `tty` screens back and forth fine. `lightdm` is running

I went to `tty1` and tried opening a browser by typing `google-chrome`. I got an error message saying `gtk-warning: cannot open display`.

After some more digging I figured out I could do `export DISPLAY=:0` and then run GUI apps.

The first thing I did was install the compiz manager, and - as I suspected, unity was disabled. So I re-enabled it, along with openGL (and some other stuff that unity required). Still nothing.

I kept trying different things, but to no avail. Finally, I think I'm on to *something* - almost every single app I'm tryng to run complains about not being able to load `libGL.so.1`. I've googled for that, and ended up installing a package called `libgl1-mesa-glx`, but even after rebooting I'm still getting the problem.

Another thing I've noticed is that **there's no `xorg.xconf`** file in `/etc/X11/`. There are a few backups and a failsafe `conf` files. I tried stopping lightdm, then copying some of them to it, like so:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo cp xorg.xcong-backup-14091923423.conf xorg.conf
sudo service lightdm start
```

But then it fails to start. Removing the file solves the issue. I have tried with several of the backups, but nothing.

I'm still suspecting that `libgGL.so.1` thing. I can locate it on the computer in a few places, here are a few relevant ones I think:

```
/home/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/home/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/home/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/home/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

**update**
`ldconfig -p | grep libGL` told me that the library had a symlink to the wrong directory (namely, `/usr/lib/` instead of `/home/usr/lib`). I've added a symlink there, and now nautilus launches when logging in, but still no unity launcher or panel on top.

Comment: also, [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/332526/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgl-so-1-wrong-elf-class-elfclass32) didn't help.

Comment: I just install xubuntu-desktop and it runs fine. Clearly a problem with unity

Comment: No, it is not a problem with Unity - it is your inexperience with Linux showing completely with the list of items you said you did.  You should not be installing graphics drivers from random web-sites, you should stick to what is in the Ubuntu repositories for a reason: they are tested and they won't (often) break your system like installing from upstream will.  Also, wait for the next kernel update.  Once that happens expect your Xfce desktop to break too.  Because you aren't using Ubuntu-provided AMD/Intel drivers and likely didn't hook them in with DKMS so anew kernel won't find the modules

Comment: Also, what is `/usr/lib` doing inside of `/home`?  Your file-system is our of whack too if that is the case.

Comment: @Bill official sites for Intel and amd are hardly "random websites". The drivers provided by the repositories are outdated and don't allow me to run some games through steam (game that run very well on Windows on the same computer)