# SSH - after login: wrong elf class

Tags: 14.04, ssh, shared-library

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. When I login on a remote machine using SSH. The login works, but I can't execute any commands. I always receive this error mesesage:

```
ssh: error while loading shared libraries: libftdi.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Recently, I installed Steam and I had to reinstall a 32-bit version of libGL and and libftdi, as far as I can remember. Maybe there is a connection?

I'm really happy for any help. I just noticed this problem today when I tried to start working from my home office :)

Thanks!
Toebs

Comment: similar: http://askubuntu.com/q/216367/85326 Maybe it can help

Comment: I read that one, but there the issues is the otherway round. SSH is using the 32bit libs instead of the 64bit libs?

Comment: Does no one know how to attack this problem at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had several exports in my .bashrc. The server is running suse and I'm running Ubuntu. Clearing the .bashrc solved the issue.