# How to install steam client?

Tags: steam, libraries

I need some help. I just downloaded the Steam client from the web and I can't open it because some software is missing.

The legend says: `You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:libc.so.6`

First it asks me to install these:
`libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386`

How do I proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steam: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64](http://askubuntu.com/questions/216367/steam-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgl-so-1-wrong-elf-class-elfcla)

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386

sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

sudp apt-get install libc6:i386
```

if it didn't work then try installing the 64-bit version